# Why is my answer deleted?

Tags: support, answers

I have a question about my Ask Ubuntu post: [Ubuntu 20.04 ACPI errors after suspend: cannot release Mutex](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1330880/ubuntu-20-04-acpi-errors-after-suspend-cannot-release-mutex/1338056#1338056)

After I realized a persistent error message, I searched for it and found the exact problem on someone else's identical system (both XPS 15s with Ubuntu 20.04). One of the answers wrote "solved:" and suggested a solution, but it did not work for me so I wrote about it. I just came back to check if there are any new solutions, but to my surprise, the answer was deleted by [Ravexina](https://askubuntu.com/users/264781/ravexina). I would just like to know why.

Comment: Just wanna confirm that your post was deleted because it was a question posted as an answer.

Answer (score 5):

I don't have enough rep to see your deleted answer. But based on your description in this meta post, it seems your answer wasn't an answer at all. But it's a follow-up question.

If that was the case, it was rightfully deleted and what you should do instead is create a new question. You can link to that question in your new post and mention what you tried and what didn't work for you.

I recommend checking [the tour](https://askubuntu.com/tour) and some posts in [the help center](https://askubuntu.com/help) for more details on how the site works.

- [Tour](https://askubuntu.com/tour)
- [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://askubuntu.com/help/deleted-answers)
- [How do I write a good answer?](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: It was indeed a question, not an answer. Here's a screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/RrMJLW0.png

Comment: That sort of question is generally best posted as a comment, as it confirms a point, adds a detail, then requests a follow-up answer 